# Why does the PE sections change between runs?

Tags: c++, memory, process, portable-executable

I have stumbled on a problem that I hope you could help me understand.

In my application i have a snapshot function that copies(ReadProcessMemory or memcpy, same result) all of its code + read only data sections and writes them to a file. I then have a verification function that reads the file and does a memcmp on what's in the file and what's on memory.

If I run the snapshot function and then run the verification function in the same session, it will keep saying that they are identical no matter how many times I run the verification.

When I take the snapshot in one session and then restart the app and run verification it seems completely random if the memory is identical or not, sometimes it works for 3-4 restarts of the application but sooner or later it doesn't think that the data in the file is identical to the pe section code.

Here's a link of the comparison of the pe code section between runs:

http://i45.tinypic.com/4kad7b.jpg

it's always the same thing, it's changing one character to another(in this case ? to an elevated 1) but from and to what character is always different.

Can anyone explain why this is happening? Should it be like this, if so why? or am I doing something wrong?

Note: I've tested this in both debug and release with and without a debugger attached.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For security reasons modern operating systems randomize in-memory layout of processes. The mechanism is called [Address Space Layout Randomization (ALSR)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization).

In case of a vulnerability in an executable this makes it much more complicated to inject foreign code into the application by an attack.

Comment: Yea I saw that link before posting but unless I'm missing something, that's not what's causing my problem. I'm saving relative addresses to the memory in my files and they are mapped to absolute addresses when reading in the file, taking to account what the new module address is(where the PE data is located). And as we can see in the comparison it seems to work, the data is almost identical except that 1 byte gets replaced with another byte in some places.

Comment: Ah now I get it, the module changes address which I account for but the problem is that the PE code sections contain absolute addresses when it's loaded in memory, these addresses are modified by the help of the .reloc section in the PE file when the exe is run.

So what I need to do to get this to work is to use the .reloc section to modify the addresses in my saved file before I make the comparison.